# Best approach to make class design if we have two class as bellow :

Tags: swift, oop, design-patterns

Best approach to make class design if we have two class as below:

```
class Teacher {
    var name
    var age
    var TechId
}

class Student {
    var name
    var age
    var StdID
}
```

I try it using that :

```
class Person {
    var name
    var age
}

class Student : Person {
    var StdID
}

class Teacher : Person {
    var TechID
}
```

But now problem is that student become teacher and vice versa.

Can you any one provided best solutions for that using Swift?

Comment: Why do you need a special ID for each class?

Comment: Its only example where student class and teacher class have also some extra variables and functions. That we need to handle .

Comment: Okay, then put those properties in the subclasses. The ID doesn't have to be separate, does it?

Comment: What do you mean by `student become teacher and vice versa.`?

Comment: Look if we need to know teacher is a student or not the how we check ? What relation we need to keep track of that?

Comment: @Sweeper that mean student class may have a teacher object and teacher class may have student object. Because both are allow to become teacher and student at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> But now problem is that student become teacher and vice versa.

If you can change back and forth like this, I'd first suggest a concrete and distinct object to capture what precisely is transitioning from one to the other:

```
class Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}
```

Note, in your example, you are considering this `Person` to be what other languages consider to be an abstract/virtual class. But I'm suggesting that you want to make this a concrete object (the actual person) that you instantiate.

The question then becomes how you represent "student" and "teacher". One simple pattern is to consider it a question of membership in some relevant collection:

```
typealias StudentID = String
var students: [StudentID: Person]

typealias TeacherID = String
var teachers: [TeacherID: Person]
```

In that case, transitioning from a student to a teacher (or vice versa) is merely a question of adding/removing from the appropriate dictionaries.

The above is a bit constrained, though. For example, what if you wanted to keep track of more student-specific properties (e.g. enrollment date, etc.) or teacher-specific properties (e.g. hire date, social security number, annual salary, etc.). This suggests you might want specific types for these student and teacher types:

```
class Student {
    let studentID: String
    let person: Person
}

class Teacher {
    let teacherID: String
    let person: Person
}
```

And then your students and teachers collections become simple arrays:

```
var students: [Student]
var teachers: [Teacher]
```

But by making the `Person` a property (rather than a base class), if you know which person is associated with a particular "student id", you can now associate that person with a particular "teacher id", too. But the idea is the same, it's merely a question of membership in the appropriate collection/type, not an issue of trying to change the inherent type of the person.

---

The alternative is a protocol oriented pattern:

```
protocol Person {
    var name: String { get }
    var age: Int { get }
}

struct Student: Person {
    let studentID: String
    var name: String
    var age: Int

    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        studentID = UUID().uuidString
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }

    init(person: Person) {
        self.init(name: person.name, age: person.age)
    }
}

struct Teacher: Person {
    let teacherID: String
    var name: String
    var age: Int

    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        teacherID = UUID().uuidString
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }

    init(person: Person) {
        self.init(name: person.name, age: person.age)
    }
}
```

This captures your notion that `Person` is an abstract type that simply conforms to having certain properties. It avoids any ambiguity that `Person` is not a type, itself, but merely a protocol to which types have to conform. You can only instantiate concrete `Student` and `Teacher` objects.

But then, if you want to create a `Teacher` from a `Student`, you can do:

```
let fred = Student(name: "Fred", age: 22)

let teacher = Teacher(person: fred)
```

Note, though, that this doesn’t “change” `fred` into a `Teacher`, but rather creates a new `Teacher` whose `Person` properties are copies of those of `fred`.

Comment: What is the student id of teacher object that you creat using that line of code " `let teacher = Teacher(person: fred)` " ?

Comment: @M.ShahzadQamar - In my protocol-oriented example, I just happen to make sure that every new `Teacher` and `Student` have their own unique id numbers, but you could easily change it to have rendition in which you supply the id and use that in the new instance. All of this having been said, I'd go OOP (object oriented) here (the first half of my answer), not POP (protocol-oriented), as it much better captures the model when dealing with real world objects like people, teachers, and students.

Comment: At about 42:15 into [Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/), Apple explains that in the POP world, you might want to still use reference types when, "Copying or comparing instances doesn't make sense". They suggest this rule might apply when dealing with "Window" instances. But the same applies in your case. E.g., POP statements like "copy student A as teacher B" or "is student C equal to student D" just don't make any sense when dealing with real students and teachers in the real world. Fine for coordinates or integers, but not people.

Answer (score 2):

For Swift, I would recommend something like this:

```
protocol Person {
    var name: String { get }
    var age: Int { get }
}

struct Teacher: Person {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

struct Student: Person {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}
```

Use a Protocol to define the person. And use a Struct for Teacher and Student because once created you would not change their details as a Struct is immutable. Both Teacher and Student conform to Person protocol.

To test if a person is a Teacher or Student, you could do this:

```
func test(person: Person) {
    switch person {
    case is Teacher:
        print("teacher")
    case is Student:
        print("student")
    default:
        preconditionFailure("Unknown person type")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are repeat name and age in both **Teacher** and **Student** ?

Comment: Structs do not allow inheritance. By conforming to the protocol 'Person' you are saying that the struct has those items, but you still need to create them. I suggest you read up about classes and structs in Swift to understand more.

Comment: Yep, but just to qualify that comment, you can inherit the default protocol implementations of methods, just not its properties.